# How to identify distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having difficulty grasping the definition of 'distinct eigenvalues' and how to identify them. By this, I mean what makes these eigenvalues distinct and is there a procedure for identifying them in a diagonal matrix? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  The eigenvalues are the values on the diagonal of a diagonal matrix.  If they are all different, the eigenvalues are distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example. If the square matrix $A$ has the characteristic polynomial

$p_A( \lambda)= \lambda( \lambda-1)^3(\lambda -2)^2$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ (counted with algebraic multiplicities) are

$\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2= \lambda_3=\lambda_4=1, \lambda_5= \lambda_6=2.$

The distinct eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,1, 2.$

Answer (score 2):

When eigenvalues are *not* distinct, it means that an eigenvalue appears more than once as a root of the characteristic polynomial.  In geometric terms, it means that there are multiple linearly independent vectors that the matrix scales by the same constant.  For instance, the dilation $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $\langle 1, 0 \rangle \mapsto \langle 2, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0, 1 \rangle \mapsto \langle 0, 2 \rangle$ has eigenvectors $\langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0, 1 \rangle$, both of whose eigenvalues are $2$.  So this transformation does not have distinct eigenvalues.

As a general rule, if $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then $\alpha$ has multiplicity greater than $1$ $\iff \alpha$ is also a root of the derivative $f'$ of $f$.  To see why this is true, suppose $\alpha$ is a repeated root, allowing us to write $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some $g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.  As a consequence of the product rule, you'll see that $(x-\alpha)$ also divides $f'$, indicating that $\alpha$ is a root of $f'$ as well.  This gives a fast, convenient method with which to check whether a given eigenvalue is repeated, though you can also use polynomial long division and check if $\alpha$ is also a root of $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x-\alpha}$.

Note that the "derivative test" will only tell you *whether* $\alpha$ is a repeated root; you might need polynomial long division to determine its exact multiplicity.  I say "might" because context clues can give away information.  For instance, suppose your characteristic polynomial is of degree $3$ and you've found two roots, one of which has multiplicity $2$.  Then the remaining eigenvalue cannot be repeated as the total number of roots (counting multiplicity) is *at most* equal to the degree of the characteristic polynomial (and it **is** equal when you're working over an [algebraically closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) such as the complex numbers).  Likewise, if your characteristic polynomial is of degree $n$ and you've found $n$ eigenvalues, then none can repeat per this sum-of-multiplicities fact.